# Is there a formula for finding the lowest factor of a number

Tags: algorithms

Is there a simple formula/algorithm to find the lowest factor of a number other than one?

Thanks!

Comment: Search is simple, but for large numbers quite inefficient.

Comment: If there were such a formula, you could break RSA codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't!  The best you can to without advanced methods is “trial division”: check if the  number is divisible by 2, then by 3, then by 5, 7, 11, and so on.

You only need to check divisibility by prime numbers.  For example, you don't have to check if it is divisible by 6, since if it were, it would also be divisible by 2 and 3, which you would have checked already.

You only need to check up to the square root of the original number.  For example, when checking for divisors of 293, you only have to check up to $\sqrt{293} = 17.11$.  When you find that none of 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, or 17 divides 293, you can stop and conclude that 293 is prime.

For advanced methods, see Wikipedia's article on [integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization). For a method of intermediate difficulty, try the [Pollard rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm). Note that finding the smallest factor of a number is in general as hard as finding a complete factorization, because the number you are factoring might be a product of two prime numbers, and finding the smaller automatically gives you the larger.