# Constructing a Function $f(n,x)$ with Specific Properties

Tags: calculus, number-theory, functions

Let there be a smooth, continuous function $f(n,x)$ where $n$ is an odd semiprime, which is the product of two odd primes $p$ and $q$, where $p$ is the smaller factor and is strictly less than $\sqrt{n}$. The only zero of $f(n,x)$ for $1<x<\sqrt{n}$ is $x=p$. There can be other zeros outside of that range. What is an example of such $f(n,x)$, in which the explicit definition (using mathematical operators, math symbols, etc.) of the function does not require you to know $p$ or $q$? Anything not including $\sum$ or $\prod$ over $n$ terms is accepted, ie. it must be closed form.

For example, I already know $$f_1(n,x)=(\cos(\frac{n}{x} \pi)\cos(x\pi))-1$$ and $$f_2(n,x)=\sin^2(\frac{n}{x}\pi)+\sin^2(x \pi)$$ but I want other functions. On that note, while sine and cosine are allowed, functions that don't use them are preferred.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96224/discussion-on-question-by-quote-dave-constructing-a-function-fn-x-with-speci).

Comment: @AloizioMacedo May you remove your comment please? It is no longer necessary. Thank you.

Comment: Note sure if this is helpful for anyone, but here are graphs of the two functions mentioned above:  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vdibagqx95  (Move the slider to change the value of $n$.)

Comment: @SelrachDunbar It does look interesting to watch, so that's a plus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think no simple formula/expression for such a function exists.

Reason:  If there were such a formula, one could substitute a value for a semiprime $N=pq$ into it and then solve the equation $f(N,x)=0$ for $x$. (Alternatively one could just graph the function $g(x):=f(N,x)$ and find the value of $x$ for which the output changed from negative to positive.)  The solution would, of course, be $p$, the smallest positive factor of $N$.

Bottom line:  If there were an expression for such a function, it would give us an algorithm for finding the lowest factor of a number.  Which would be great!  ... except sadly, according to this post:   [Is there a formula for finding the lowest factor of a number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732831/is-there-a-formula-for-finding-the-lowest-factor-of-a-number) ... there isn't, in general, such an algorithm.

Comment: But you are not sure there isn't any formula?

Comment: I am pretty certain that at this point in time none is known.  As it says in the other post, "If there were such a formula, you could break RSA codes."  And RSA Public Key encryption is what all secure internet transactions depend on ... so there is *a lot* of interest/money to be made by breaking such codes.

Comment: Actually, not ALL of communication rely on RSA anymore. A lot does, but some is encrypted by other methods. RSA, of course, is still the most popular, but because of advances of computing power, people have been developing other methods, just as a preparation for the inevitable advance that make efficient factorization possible.

Comment: That's good to know.  First I have heard about other methods being employed, but RSA encryption has been around a long time, so it makes sense that other methods are being developed and used.

Comment: I gave a new definition of the function. Is this new function possible?

Comment: It appears $f_1$ is always negative and clearly $f_2$ is always positive (with zeros of occurring only at the factors of $n$).  As such, any function of the form $f=a \cdot f_2 - b \cdot f_1$, where $a$ and $b$ are both strictly positive would also work.

Comment: Huh, I would need to check that out.

Comment: Ok, it works, but like I said, I would like different functions, preferably ones that doesn't rely on the example functions :)

Comment: I understand.  I can't think of any other expressions.  :)

Comment: Perhaps someone really good with trig identities could take a linear combination of the example functions and simplify it to something nicer (but I doubt all reference to $sin$ and $cos$ would disappear).